# Airpush Application information not avaliable

Tags: android, airpush

I have integrated Airpush Bundle SDK in my new android app following this [documentation](http://manage.airpush.com/docs/index.php?title=Bundle_SDK_1.0_Documentation). The problem is I am not seeing any ad. I have provided the MainActivity.java, AndroidManifest.xml & LogCat below. What is the meaning of the message:

> Application information not avaliable

and what do I need to do in order to fix this problem?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package mg.mynewandroidapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.oadx.khsz210697.AdListener;
import com.oadx.khsz210697.AdListener.AdType;
import com.oadx.khsz210697.MA;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView listView1;
    private MA ma;
    private AdListener adCallbackListener;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



                 if(ma==null)
                        ma=new MA(this, adCallbackListener, true);
                 ma.callSmartWallAd();
                 ma.call360Ad(this, 0, false, null);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    //Displaying Cached SmartWall Ad
    try {
          ma.showCachedAd(this, AdType.smartwall);
        } catch (Exception e) 
         {
          super.onBackPressed();
         }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mg.mynewandroidapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ILYSTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.oadx.XXXXXXXXXX.APPID" android:value="MY_APP_ID" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.oadx.XXXXXXXXXX.APIKEY" android:value="android*MY_API_KEY"/>
        <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.oadx.XXXXXXXXXX.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity android:name="com.oadx.XXXXXXXXXX.BrowserActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.oadx.XXXXXXXXXX.VActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity> 
        <service android:name="com.oadx.XXXXXXXXXX.LService" android:exported="false"></service>
        <receiver android:name="com.oadx.XXXXXXXXXX.BootReceiver" android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LogCat**

```
11-21 21:06:50.229: I/BunSDK(11425): Status code: 200
11-21 21:06:50.229: I/BunSDK(11425): 360 Json: {"status":204,"message":"ADS Not Available"}
11-21 21:06:50.829: I/BunSDK(11425): Status code: 200
11-21 21:06:50.829: I/BunSDK(11425): SmartWall JSON: {"status":100,"count":0,"url":"","message":"Application information not avaliable"}
```